# Java Generics List

Tags: java, list

Following is an example of Generics with wild card

```
public static void printListItems(List<object> list) {
        for (Object listItem : list)
            System.out.println(listItem);
    }
```

In this example we want to print list items of any type but it can’t print `List<Integer>`, `List<String>` etc. because they are not subtypes of `List<Object>`. This problem can be solved using unbounded wildcard.

```
public static void printListItems(List<?> list) {
    for (Object listItem : list)
        System.out.println(listItem);
}
```

I read this above code in Java tutorial. For the first example , it says it cannot work because `List<String>` is not sublass of `List<Object>`.

Then why it is so that in the second example the for loop is working with taking listItem as dataType of `Object` and iterating through `List<String>` elements.

Comment: I believe it's clearly explained: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/unboundedWildcards.html

Comment: You might also want to read "[Difference between <? super T> and <? extends T> in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4343202/5221149)", keeping in mind that `?` implicitly means `? extends Object`, or as the [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.5.1) says it: *The wildcard `? extends Object` is equivalent to the unbounded wildcard `?`*.

Comment: Because every element (String, Integer, whatever) is an Object.

Answer (score 0):

You are running into a false contradiction because you are equating the relationship between `List<String>` and `List<Object>` to the relationship between `String` and `Object`.

In the first example, the compiler will yell at you if you attempt to call `printListItem`s with a `List<String>`, because `List<String>` does not extend `List<Object>`.

In other words: A list of strings cannot be treated as a list of objects, because (according to the type system) a list of strings *is not* a list of objects.

In the second example, the compiler will not yell at you, because you are treating the elements of the `List`, which are `String`s, as `Object`s. Unlike the case with the lists, `String` does extend `Object`.

In other words: A string can be treated as an object, because (according to the type system) a string *is* an object.

Answer (score 0):

when the *type-declaration* of `generic class` contain `wildcard character`, its **subclass type** can be extend in two dimension.

---

E.g. Collection<?extends Number>

- its subclass type can be extend **in dimension Collection**, for `List and Set` are all subclass type of `Collection` so `List<? extends Number> and Set<? extends Number>`are all **subclass type** of `Collection<? extends Number>`
- its subclass type can be extend **in dimension Number**, because `Integer 、Double` are all subclass type of `Number` so `Collection<Double> and Collection<Integer>` are all **subclass** of Collection<? extends Number>

---

about your second, as  **Andreas** explained *in comment*, List is equal to List<? extend Object> and based on the second dimension extend List<String> is **subclass** of List<?>

Answer (score 0):

What you've done is not generic. This is a generic function

```
public static <T> void printListItems(List<T> list) {
    for (T listItem : list) {
        System.out.println(listItem);
    }
}
```

Example:

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main {
    public static <T> void printListItems(List<T> list) {
        for (T listItem : list) {
            System.out.println(listItem);
        }
    }

    // arguments are passed using the text field below this editor
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> l = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5));
        List<String> s = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("Hello", "World"));
        printListItems(l);
        printListItems(s);
    }
}
```

### Output

```
1
2
3
4
5
Hello
World
```